# Strategies to building a database of 30m images

Tags: database

## Summary

I am facing the task of building a searchable database of about 30 million images (of different sizes) associated with their metadata. I have no real experience with databases so far.

## Requirements

There will be only a few users, the database will be almost read-only, (if things get written then by a controlled automatic process), downtime for maintenance should be no big issue. We will probably perform more or less complex queries on the metadata.

## My Thoughts

My current idea is to save the images in a folder structure and build a relational database on the side that contains the metadata as well as links to the images themselves. I have read about document based databases. I am sure they are reliable, but probably the images would only be accessible through a database query, is that true? In that case I am worried that future users of the data might be faced with the problem of learning how to query the database before actually getting things done.

## Question

What database could/should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Storing big fields that are not used in queries outside the "lookup table" is recommended for certain database systems, so it does not seem unusual to store the 30m images in the file system.

As to "which database", that depends on the frameworks you intend to work with, how complicated your queries usually are, and what resources you have available.

I had some complicated queries run for minutes on MySQL that were done in seconds on PostgreSQL and vice versa. Didn't do the tests with SQL Server, which is the third RDBMS that I have readily available.

One thing I can tell you: Whatever you can do in the DB, do it in the DB. You won't even nearly get the same performance if you pull all the data from the database and then do the matching in the framework code.

A second thing I can tell you: Indexes, indexes, indexes!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like the data is very relational so a non-relational DBMS like MongoDB might be the way to go. With any DBMS you will have to use queries to get information from it. However, if your worried about future users, you could put a software layer between the user and DB that makes querying easier.

Storing images in the filesystem and metadata in the DB is a much better idea than storing large Blobs in the DB (IMHO). I would also note that the filesystem performance will be better if you have many folders and subfolders rather than 30M images in one big folder *(citation needed)*

Comment: from my description the data does not sound very relational, but I think it is, because the meta data describes the origin and type of the image which is shared amongst a couple of them.